# Lazily Mapping an Array Using a Throwing Closure

Tags: arrays, swift, throw, lazy-sequences

When lazily mapping an array of values, I receive an instance of type `LazyMapSequence` as expected:

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.7 (swiftlang-5.7.0.127.4 clang-1400.0.29.50).
Type :help for assistance.
  1> let numbers = Array(1...5)
numbers: [Int] = 5 values {
  [0] = 1
  [1] = 2
  [2] = 3
  [3] = 4
  [4] = 5
}
  2> let squares = numbers.lazy.map { $0 * $0 }
squares: LazyMapSequence<LazySequence<[Int]>.Elements, Int> = {
  _base = 5 values {
    [0] = 1
    [1] = 2
    [2] = 3
    [3] = 4
    [4] = 5
  }
  _transform =
}
```

However, if the `map(_:)` method receives a throwing a closure instead, the mapping is not performed lazily, and I receive an array instead:

```
  3> func square(_ x: Int) throws -> Int {
  4.     return x * x
  5. }
  6> let squares = try numbers.lazy.map(square)
squares: [Int] = 5 values {
  [0] = 1
  [1] = 4
  [2] = 9
  [3] = 16
  [4] = 25
}
```

Why is that, and how do I lazily map an array of values using a throwing closure?

Comment: Okay, I can kind of see why this is. It's because the `map` method will rethrow any error and that error would need to be caught where the method is invoked. There would need to be some kind of concept like a "ThrowingLazyMapSequence". Does anyone know a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is

```
extension LazySequennce {
    func tryMap<U>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Element) throws -> U) -> LazyMapSequence<Self.Elements, Result<U, Error>> {
        self.map { x in Result(catching: { try transform(x) }) }
    }
}
```

Note that the element type of the sequence is `Result<U, Error>`. We essentially "catch" the error whenever any is thrown. The error has to be caught because when iterating over any `Sequence`, the protocol requires that no errors are thrown.

As for why `map(square)` is not lazy, it is exactly as you have observed. [`LazySequenceProtocol.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/lazysequenceprotocol/map(_:)) takes a closure that does not throw.

```
func map<U>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Element) -> U) 
    -> LazyMapSequence<Self.Elements, U>
```

When you pass in the throwing method, it instead calls [`Sequence.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/map(_:)):

```
func map<T>(_ transform: (Self.Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]
```

which is not lazy.

This would all be solved if there were a method that looked like:

```
func tryMap<U>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Element) throws -> U) 
    -> LazyThrowingMapSequence<Self.Elements, U>
```

However, such a `LazyThrowingMapSequence` type cannot conform to `Sequence`, because its iterator cannot conform to `IteratorProtocol`. Its iterator's `next` method *throws*, but `IteratorProtocol` requires that `next` does not throw.

It is theoretically possible to write `LazyThrowingMapSequence` by just adding `throws` to a few places to `LazyMapSequence`. ([Source code of `LazyMapSequence` is here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/stdlib/public/core/Map.swift#L18)) But using it would be a pain, since you cannot iterate over it with a `for` loop, and it doesn't have any of those convenient methods from the `Sequence` protocol.

Comment: Thank you. Using the Result enum is a very good workaround for my case (although it might not be a perfectly pretty solution perhaps). I will go that, thanks!